# horizontal scrollbar appears unless I set margin-right=15px

Tags: html, css

I am getting a horizontal scrollbar; I don't need to set `overflow-x` to hidden as only one page might really still need the scrollbar. the point is that I don't understand why the scrollbar appear.

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;

    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'itcmd' !important;
}

body {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
    background-color: #F3F3F3 !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

as you see in some whitespace in red recatangle appear though there is nothing to show

[image]

the only way to avoid the scrollbar is by setting margin-right=15 in the css for html

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 15px;

    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'itcmd' !important;
}
```

why am I getting the scrollbar? is there a way to setup my css correctly to utilize the full width while avoiding scrollbar unless I need to

Comment: why do you want margin right on the html element?

Comment: I don't want it; but it is the only way worked to have the scrollbar disappeared. this is why I have created this post

Comment: You need to create a [mcve] demonstrating your actual problem then as with the code you have supplied it's hard to know what you are talking about

Comment: what is mvce? any other details I can provide?

Comment: Try adding `overflow: hidden` on `html{}` to really test if anything is going beyond the page and triggers scrollbar. Also you use this CSS `*{outline: 1px solid red}` for same testing.

Comment: thanks @ismi I will try it out

Answer (score 1):

Some of your content is taking more width than it should which is causing the scrollbar. Check if you have used negative margin. You can try adding overflow hidden on inner divs one by one using dev tools until you find the culprit.
Or else share the complete code.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to add margin and padding 0 to both html and body

```
html, body{margin:0;padding:0;}
```